# An error occurs during the migration of the postgresql database to the gbase database

Tags: postgresql, transfer, kingbase

When you use GbaseMigrationToolkit to migrate the postgresql database to the gbase database, the primary key is abnormal, the abnormal items are of the primary key type BIGSERIAL, and the default value in the source database is not migrated successfully.

At the time of migration, all are selected, but there will be an error. The error is the default value of the primary key bigserial.
In addition, the external structure and data can be migrated normally. But the source data east has defaut, it is not migrated, this estimate is to add attributes.
lvachar is required for all string types, but the migration process will automatically convert the length of 255 or less to varchar.
Anything greater than 255 would be lvachar. If there were a way to convert everything to lvachar, the latter problem wouldn't exist.
Now you have varchar and lvarchar, and you can insert data normally. But when the query will report an error, I deal with
Yes add the attribute FXPAD_VARCHAR-1 and the garbled problem attribute ifx_use_strenc=true. The problem is that the first character of the varchar value is missing